# How can I list all object with certain prefix and postfix?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a code chunk that runs like this:

```
library(SummarizedExperiment)

for (i in seq_along(sce_list))
 {
     r <- rowData(sce_list[[i]])$use
     c <- colData(sce_list[[i]])$use
     tt=(sce_list[[i]])[r,c]
      assign(paste0("sce_",i,".qc"),tt)
 }
```

I would like to store the objects **"sce_",i,".qc"** from above code in a list and access them through a loop.

In principle what I want to do is:

make a function:

```
sceDataDim <- function(sce){
        print(paste(metadata(sce)$name[1], dim(sce)[1], "genes", dim(sce)[2], "cells"))
```

and then use the function like this

```
sceDataDim(sce_1.qc)
```

The above code works fine. However, when I try to run a loop, I run into trouble:

```
for (i in 1:4)
sceDataDim(paste0("sce_",i,".qc"))

error
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘metadata’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

Any suggestions ????

EDIT:

```
dput(sce_list)
list(<S4 object of class structure("SingleCellExperiment", package = "SingleCellExperiment")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("SingleCellExperiment", package = "SingleCellExperiment")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("SingleCellExperiment", package = "SingleCellExperiment")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("SingleCellExperiment", package = "SingleCellExperiment")>)
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, maybe `dput(sce_list)`.

Comment: Hi, where shall I introduce dput(sce_list)? I am sorry for the reproducible example, these are few lines os a very large code chunk.

Comment: It would be nice to have data for testing. If the data is not too big, then copy paste output of `dput(sce_list)` into your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget` with `ls` and its `pattern` argument :

```
sce_1.qc <- "foo"
sce_2.qc <- "bar"

your_list <- mget(ls(pattern="sce_\\d+\\.qc"))
your_list
# $sce_1.qc
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $sce_2.qc
# [1] "bar"
```

`\d+` matches a sequence of digits